# Difference between classes in Java vs JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I have some experience with C# and Java, but I'm trying to learn javascript/node.js. I can't quite figure out what the problem is with this code.

So I have my `main.js` file, and it has this code:

```
const MyClass = require("./MyClass");
let myclass = new MyClass("my string!");

myclass.repeatString();
```

The `MyClass` it's calling has this code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    repeatString() {
        console.log(myString);
    }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

When I try to run this, I get `ReferenceError: myString is not defined` when it tries to execute that `repeatString()` method. What am I doing wrong/what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike some languages like Java where we can reference variables within a class without using `this`, `this` binding [behaves much differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) in JavaScript, as does scoping.

In Java, this is legal:

```
class Test {
  int i;
  void method() {
    System.out.print(i); // <-- Java compiler knows to look for the `i` on the class instance (technically it first looks for `i` locally in the scope of `method` and the goes to look on the class)
  }
}
```

In JavaScript, we don't have this behavior, there's no such thing as a class variable ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)).

```js
class Test {
  i; // <-- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
  method() {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

For your example, this means you are always required to use `this` when referencing variables present in a class (technically on an object instance).

Thus you must use `this.myString`:

```
repeatString() {
  console.log(this.myString);
}
```

You are getting the `Reference Error` because the engine tries to find a variable called `myString` starting from the scope of `repeatString` and upward and there aren't any. The only scope that has a variable `myString` is the one within the constructor function, and that scope is unreachable from `repeatString`.

Classes in JavaScript are radically different ([here's an overview](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html)) than Java, even though the syntax looks very similar.

Answer (score 1):

To indicate that you're referring to a property of the object named `myString` instead of a variable with the same name, your `console.log()` invocation should read:

```
console.log(this.myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

To print myString varible use `console.log(this.myString);`

Answer (score 1):

To access the variable of a class, use `this`. variable name.

Please check the code below.

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    repeatString() {
        console.log(this.myString);
    }
}

const myClass = new MyClass('Hello');
myClass.repeatString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class member-variable in JavaScript can be accessed using **this.member-variable** syntax.

The correct way to solve the problem is following:

Main.js

```
const MyClass = require("./MyClass");
let myclass = new MyClass("my string!");
myclass.repeatString();
```

MyClass.js

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    repeatString() {
        console.log(this.myString);
    }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```